# Requests post data with dictionary format error

Tags: python, python-requests, mechanize

the formdata which will be send to the server looks like that:
[image: Formdata]

I don't get it to post it correctly to the server. I have tried it like that:

```
payload = {
    "ad_id": ad_id,
    "ad_type": "1",
    "csrf_token": crsf_token,
    "messages": [{'content': 'message to server', 'message_type': 'text'}],
    "user_id": "9020446"
}
#
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Origin": "https://www.wg-gesucht.de",
    "Referer": f"https://www.wg-gesucht.de/nachricht-senden.html?message_ad_id={ad_id}"
}
res = browser.post('https://www.wg-gesucht.de/ajax/api/Smp/api.php?action=conversations', payload, headers=headers)
```

and i also tried it just like that:

```
"messages": ['message to server']
```

but i am always getting a 401 error.

Would be great if anyone could help me.

Best regards!

Comment: Do you know what 401 means? What is the authentication method the server expects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the posttype to "json", this fixed the error for me:

```
res = browser.post('https://www.wg-gesucht.de/ajax/api/Smp/api.php?action=conversations', json=payload, headers=headers)
```

Still thank you for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "requests" library in python

```py
import requests
payload = {
    "ad_id": ad_id,
    "ad_type": "1",
    "csrf_token": crsf_token,
    "messages": [{'content': 'message to server', 'message_type': 'text'}],
    "user_id": "9020446"
}
#
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Origin": "https://www.wg-gesucht.de",
    "Referer": f"https://www.wg-gesucht.de/nachricht-senden.html?message_ad_id={ad_id}"
}
res = requests.post('https://www.wg-gesucht.de/ajax/api/Smp/api.php?action=conversations', data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Comment: OP is already using requests library I believe. What is different about your answer that makes it work? (Assuming it does)

Comment: Correct, i am using mechanicalsoup. It inherates from the requests library. Your code didn't work, the problem was we have to send it as a json file